# Unique constraint violation on Magento 1.4.0 to 1.6.2.0 upgrade

Tags: magento

I'm running an upgrade on an existing Magento site.  After about 10 minutes, Magento reports an exception, and when I check the error report file in /var/report I see the following error message and stack dump:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:223:"Error in file: "/var/www/vhosts/mymagesite/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-8' for key 'UNQ_BY_CUSTOMER'";i:1;s:952:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/mymagesite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mymagesite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.4.0.0.7', '1.6.1.0')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mymagesite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.4.0.0.7', '1.6.1.0')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mymagesite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mymagesite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(412): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mymagesite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(338): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mymagesite/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mymagesite/index.php(80): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:16:"/index.php/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

The general advice elsewhere on the Internet is to change `<initStatements>` in `app/etc/config.xml` to read:

```
<initStatements>SET NAMES utf8; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;</initStatements>
```

However, disabling your databases integrity constraint system is a guaranteed path to incredibly difficult to support and troubleshoot issues later. It is a hack that makes the upgrade script not crash with an error, it does NOT actually fix the problem in any way shape or form.

Can the StackOverflow community assist with either a better solution, or a good explanation as to why disabling integrity checking in MySQL is a good idea?

Comment: disabled all extensions reverted to default theme on upgrade time?

Comment: I've not disabled extensions or reverted to the default theme.  I'm unsure how doing so might resolve this problem.  If third party extensions have caused this error, then the "damage" has already been done to the database and disabling them won't undo it.

Comment: Hey Jim :) the reason why you should disable them is the way that extensions usually work. Magento way is to extend and rewrite if you need to change something and extensions are rewriting some version of magento and are not updating it to latest versions. So basically the error is that extension rewrites something and magento has updated this part = conflict

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This table is ok to truncate.
http://docs.nexcess.net/magento-database-maintenance

Its one of a handfull of tables gathering site usage information which are not critical to the operation of magento. (It does effect the customer reports, if your using those.)

The problem is with the migration script from:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php
```

Its altering a column which used to default to NULL to default to not null.

```
ALTER TABLE `report_compared_product_index` MODIFY COLUMN `customer_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT ''
```

The error is from a unique index on that column. It was null before so MySQL was ignoring the unique index. Once it was set to default to not null, NULL is no longer a valid value and it attempts to set the value of the column to 0. It gets to the second row and now its breaking the unique index and you get an error,
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8173

The 1.4x code saved data in this table which isn't compatible with the new schema.
Its also going to be pretty hard to clean up because your missing information needed to satisfy the unique index.
The quickest option is to just truncate the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy to decipher from the error message. You have a duplicate customer (or more than one duplicate customers).

Open up your customer_entity table in phpMyadmin and look for duplicates. Depending on how many customers you have you may want to go through this manually, chances are that the duplicates will be from your own testing with 'fred@test.com' style emails. You should be able to safely delete these once you have gone through the table and worked out for yourself what has gone on.

Comment: I was able to overcome the issue by running the updates form the command line (i.e. "php index.php").  If there were truly duplicate records in the database I should see the same error message regardless of whether the updates were run from the browser or the command line.