# Getting error when i am trying to migrate magento website from server to localhost

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, magento

I am trying to setup my live website into localhost i am getting these errors can any one help on this

```
Error in file: "G:\test\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Reports\sql\reports_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.0.1.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily' already exists

Trace:
#0 G:\test\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 G:\test\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.0.1')
#2 G:\test\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.0.1')
#3 G:\test\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 G:\test\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 G:\test\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 G:\test\apps\magento\htdocs\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 G:\test\apps\magento\htdocs\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Answer (score 1):

It clearly says, the `report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily` is already exists. So you need to skip this table, or clear your database and try to import again.

**Update**

The error is from a unique index on that column. It was null before so MySQL was ignoring the unique index. 
Its altering a column which used to default to NULL to default to not null.

```
ALTER TABLE `report_compared_product_index` MODIFY COLUMN `customer_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '';
```

The best option is just remove the file `G:\test\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Reports\sql\reports_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.0.1.php`, or just truncate (empty) that table, we wont need that data.

For more information please go **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123972/unique-constraint-violation-on-magento-1-4-0-to-1-6-2-0-upgrade)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply i cleared database and uploaded once again after that i am getting this error.                         Error in file: "G:test\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\sql\customer_setup\mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-1818' for key 'UNQ_BY_CUSTOMER'